# iOS Horizontal CollectionView not scrolling all the way

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a single row `collectionview` that scrolls horizontally. The `collectionview` works but it cuts off the second to last cell (labeled orange) and hides the last cell.

[image]

I have 5 cells, each of size 166x166. I have checked the `contentsize` of the `viewlayout` and it's width is 830 which is correct, yet I am unable to scroll that far.

Here is the settings in Storyboard:

[image]

And here is the code for the `collectionview`.

```
#pragma mark Collection View Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FeaturedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag: 100];
    label.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a UICollectionView or a UICollectionViewController? If you're using a collection view, perhaps part of its frame is ending up off screen.

Comment: I am using a UICollectionView within a ViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new IB default for view sizes is 600 points. If you don't use auto layout or another means to constrain the sizes, the frame will extend off screen and won't be visible. If this is happening at 320 px wide, you'll lose 240 points, which if your cells are 166 points wide, means you lose about 1 1/2 cells. About what's missing.

Make sure the collection view has a trailing constraint with constant 0 to the superview edge (or other means to ensure the sizes match, such as "equal" widths to superview).

Comment: Hey @Michael Sand thanks for the response, it looks like when I pin the trailing edge and leading edge of the collection to the superview it displays correctly. However the other constraints on my page seem to get messed up. Is there a reason this is happening?

Comment: Yes, the reason is because AutoLayout sucks. Haha, seriously something else probably is constrained to the collectionView, check either the orange or red arrow in the object bar on the left of the IB to find out what it is, or select the collection view and look at the constraints on the right inspector, under the ruler icon. If you can't identify the issue there, mark this one as solved and post screenshots to another question, I'll take a look, AutoLayout seriously is the worst.

Comment: Yeah AutoLayout seems to be a real pain. But thanks for the response.

Comment: NP, I studied AutoLayout in depth before concluding it's a disaster. The "constant" can be changed at runtime, the "equal" widths/heights constraint actually will make them different. Possibly the worst API Apple has. I try to help people where I can.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `minimumLineSpacing` and `minimumInteritemSpacing` to an equal value solved my problem for horizontal collection view.

Comment: so what if I want to only set the minimumLineSpacing!!

Comment: well, i guess this workaround only works for horizontal collection views with one single row.  Seems to me that there's some problem with Apple's implementation on calculating horizontal content size.

Comment: Ya I guess u r right. I have a single row hor collection view. that works for now. I guess. ty

Comment: every time I implement hor collection view. I face same problem and start searching again :)